# Content management system security?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am currently trying to create my own CMS system.

On the "/tools/default.aspx" page I have a log in, which when successfully logged in, redirects to "/tools/cms.aspx".

I have used the windows authentication to block unwanted access to the folders but if I type in the page "/cms/cms.aspx", I can access the CMS without logging in.

**EDIT:**

I have prevented access to the CMS but the log in doesn't work now and I can still access its folders.

/tools/web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <configuration>
      <system.web>
        <authorization>
          <deny users="?"/>
        </authorization>
      </system.web>

    <location path="default.aspx">
      <system.web>
        <authorization>
          <allow users="*"/>
        </authorization>
      </system.web>
    </location>

    <location path="styles">
      <system.web>
        <authorization>
          <allow users="?"/>
          <allow users="*"/>
        </authorization>
     </system.web>
   </location>

    <location path="images">
      <system.web>
        <authorization>
          <allow users="?"/>
          <allow users="*"/>
        </authorization>
      </system.web>
    </location>
   </configuration>
```

web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms name="CMSLogin" loginUrl="~/tools/default.aspx" protection="All" timeout="20" path="/" />
    </authentication>
    <roleManager enabled="true" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

*Removed sensitive web.config information

Login authentication attempt:

```
protected void Login1_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
{
    string userName = Login1.UserName;
    string passWord = Login1.Password;
    bool rememberUserName = Login1.RememberMeSet;

    using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["websiteContent"].ConnectionString))
    {
        sqlCon.Open();
        string SQL = "SELECT CMS_Username, CMS_Password FROM CMS_Users WHERE CMS_Username ='" + userName + "' AND CMS_Password ='" + passWord + "'";
        using (SqlCommand sqlComm = new SqlCommand(SQL, sqlCon))
        {
            sqlComm.ExecuteScalar();

            if (sqlComm.ExecuteScalar() != null)
            {
                Response.Redirect("cms.aspx");
            }
            else
            {
                Session["UserAuthentication"] = "";
            }
        }
        sqlCon.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you perhaps use `MasterPages` or `Forms Authentication` how do you have your `Authentication` setup in your .config file..?

Comment: Also when you are `"Re-Inventing the Wheel"` I would also look at implementing your own `user password` check `Sql Server. Active Directory, ...etc`

Comment: Your question sounds like you may be unintentionally mixing Forms-authentication and Active Directory authentication.  I would also like to see the Authentication setup from .config.

Comment: Can you show us your authorization & authentication sections from your web.config file?

Comment: @Penfold I have update my post. I want to use forms authentication but I also want to prevent access to anything in my CMS.

Answer (score 0):

Either you can check whether the value of session variable is null in every page on its page load event or you can just use master page and implement same check in its load event.